# base64 encoded file upload via json api endpoint encountering Status code 400

Tags: c#, xamarin, base64, http-status-code-400, refit

I'm trying to send a PDF file that is converted to Base64 to an API endpoint but I'm encountering a Status Code 400 which is Bad Request error. First, I'm converting my PDF to base64 format then send it to an API endpoint by using Refit Post. My PDF file is located in the Assets folder in my Android Project in Visual Studio. Please also see my screenshot for the http-header, http-post and Request body Json.

Here are my
[Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3h97.png)

Classes

```
public class PdfFile
{
    [JsonProperty("file")]
    public MyFile file { get; set; }
}

public class MyFile
{
    [JsonProperty("mime")]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public string Base64Data { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
interface IMyApi
{
    [Post("/upload")]
    Task UploadPdf([Body] PdfFile pdfFile, [Header("x-axa-api-key: apikey")] string apiKey);
}
```

MainActivity

```
myAPI = RestService.For<IMyApi>("https://goodmorning-axa-dev.azure-api.net");
string pdfBase64;

sendButton.Click += async delegate
            {
                Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog dialog = new EDMTDialogBuilder()
                .SetContext(this)
                .SetMessage("Sending...")
                .Build();

                try
                {
                    if (!dialog.IsShowing)
                        dialog.Show();

                    const string pdfFileName = "TEST.pdf";

                    using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(pdfFileName))
                    {                   
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            var fileContents = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();    
                            pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents));
                        }
                    }

                    var pdf = new PdfFile();
                    var file = new MyFile();
                    

                    file.MimeType = "application/pdf";
                    file.Base64Data = "base64-data=" + pdfBase64;

                    pdf.file = file;

                    await myAPI.UploadPdf(pdf, "apiKey");

                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Registration Successful", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                    if (dialog.IsShowing)
                        dialog.Dismiss();    
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                    if (dialog.IsShowing)
                        dialog.Dismiss();
                }
            };
```

When I call the UploadPdf, I always encounter the statuscode 400 Bad Request. I'm not sure if I have error in the way I implement Refit or if I did the proper way of converting my PDF to Base64. Need help.

Comment: You should probably remove your API key from the sample.

Comment: Where is the "/upload" in the URL like the sample?

Comment: @jdweng the /upload is in the IMyApi interface [Post("/upload")]

Comment: Use a sniffer and verify that request is same as requirements.  Verify the TLS version is 1.2/1.0.   Also verify the content length is not zero.

Comment: @jdweng I've never used a sniffer before. What sniffer software do you recommend? I will try it.

Comment: You can download for free either WireShark or Fiddler.  Both are very similar.   Some people use one and some people use the other.  I use both.

Comment: @jdweng yes I just downloaded fiddler and already made configurations and all. I tried it to some of my apps and the fiddler can monitor the traffic on my android device. But somehow when I use it on this app where I'm sending PDF, the fiddler cannot receive any response for this app when I'm trying to send the PDF.

Comment: Do you see the TLS in sniffer?  The TLS needs to authenticate properly before you will see the HTTP request.   The request you can view the HEADERS and validate the headers match the requirements.  The pdf will be seen in the BODY as both string and bytes.  The strings should be ASCII characters (not binary).  The Content length in header should match the number of bytes in the BODY.